# h:dataTable renders rows correctly but does not show cell values while ui:repeat does

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, datatable, uirepeat

I have the following data table.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{flightReservation.flightList}" var="flight">
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{flight.fromPlace}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{flight.toPlace}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

It does not show any data inside the cells, even though the number of rows is equal to the `flightList` size.

When I replace it by `<ui:repeat>`, then it shows the data.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{flightReservation.flightList}" var="value">
    <h:outputText value="#{value.fromPlace}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{value.toPlace}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: are you sure that your list flightList isn't empty ? try to display it in the managed bean , because your syntax (datatable) is correct ,and can you also show more details about your managed bean , and your page !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same behaviour once and it was simply an issue with the scope of variables:

You are saying, that the number of rows is correct, but the content not displayed. You are naming the variable `flight` and I assume that a value with this name has been used earlier in your markup or even used as a `<ui:param>`.

The Datatable is now iterating (internal) and generating the correct amount of rows, but when it tries to access the properties of `fligt` jsf refers to the earlier declared variable and fails to find the properties `fromPlace`, `toPLace` etc.

Try to rename your variable and see if this solves your issue.

The example bellow would produce `stringList.size()` times *yoloyolo* even if one would expect the content of the list to be shown. And if the listsource is made out of objects, any instance access on the attributes will fail cause *yoloylo* is not an object of the expected type.

```
<ui:param name="foo" value="yoloyolo" />

<h:dataTable value="#{backingBean.stringList}" var="foo">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">string</f:facet>
        - #{foo}
    </h:column> 
</h:dataTable>
```